# Running a command after any command is entered in an interactive shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

How do i run an arbitrary command like `echo Done` after **any** command has finished?

I want to be able to put any command in an interactive shell and it to return the same command when its done i.e.

```
> pwd
/home/user
Done
> ls
...
Done
> whoami
user
Done
```

I know if it is something specific like `cd` the code would be:

```
function cd () {
  builtin cd $@
  
  echo Done
}
```

but how do i do this for all commands?

Comment: `bash` or `zsh`?  Title says `zsh`, your tags mention both ...

Comment: Sorry, i know that most bash commands work on zsh

Comment: For Bash, `PROMPT_COMMAND` is the variable to look for.

Comment: define your main comman prompt (`PS1`) to run `echo "Done"` followed by whatver your default prompt is; or as Andrej just pointed out, define `PROMPT_COMMAND`

Comment: Only tag for the shell you're actually using. They aren't compatible enough for it to be safe to tag for both. (For that matter, `builtin cd $@` is severely buggy in bash; it won't work correctly for directory names with spaces unless you make it `builtin cd "$@"` _with the quotes_).

Comment: (also, the `function` keyword is a legacy of 1980s versions of ksh, but the 1980s ksh releases it comes from don't allow it to be combined with `()`, so `function funcname() {` manages to merge POSIX and ksh conventions in a way that's incompatible with _both_ POSIX and ksh; the POSIX-standard way to define a function, which all modern shells in the family support, is just `funcname() {` with no `function` preceding; see also https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).

Comment: Ohh, will keep that noted for future. I just assumed that you would need ```function``` to declare a function :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found 2 ways:

Bash (by [Andrej Podzimek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69966668/how-to-run-a-command-after-any-command-finished?noredirect=1#comment123680775_69966668) and [markp-fuso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69966668/how-to-run-a-command-after-any-command-finished?noredirect=1#comment123680801_69966668)):

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo Done'
```

ZSH:

```
precmd() { "echo Done" }
```

Comment: Do we know the OP is asking about an _interactive_ shell? `PROMPT_COMMAND` won't work in a script.

Comment: I guess in that case you could use a loop to run the function and ```echo Done```, but sry for not making it clear that it was for an interactive shell :3

Comment: In case you need this also in non-interactive shells, you could set up a `trap .... DEBUG`. This trap is executed after every shell, and works interactively and non-interactively.

Answer (score 0):

For bash:

- If set, the value of `$PROMPT_COMMAND` is executed immediately before each prompt is printed.
- It's possible to hard quote command substitutions in PS0, PS1, and PS2, which will be executed every time the respective prompt is printed.
- You can trap SIG_CHLD: `trap my-cmd CHLD`. The given command will execute in the current environment, every time a child process (command) exits, including background processes. This does not include built-ins (which are not child processes), but it does work in a script.